# Unable to sign my app with codesign

Tags: java, macos, codesign

I have had great success compiling my Jar to an app, and then making a DMG file to install it on Mac. I am now trying to sign it, but having no luck with % codesign -s

I think my syntax is correct (in this sample I'm obscuring my actual commonname with My Name 0000000000):

codesign -s "Developer ID Application: My Name (0000000000)" XMarker.app

The result is:

XMarker.app: code object is not signed at all
In subcomponent: /Users/myname/Desktop/XM-dev/XLIFF2Modules/XMarker.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk

And sure enough if I test it:

codesign -d --verbose=4 XMarker.app
XMarker.app: code object is not signed at all

If somebody could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Michael Dautermann! Your clues set me on the right trail!

Going "--deep" is not the way to go because we still fail the

```
spctl --assess --type execute XMarker.app test.
```

But the second part of his answer lead me to what worked.

So to be sure the precise, isolated answer is available to others suffering this problem, here's what works:

```
cd /Users/myname/Desktop/XM-dev/XLIFF2Modules/XMarker.app/Contents/PlugIns/

codesign -s "Developer ID Application: My Name (0000000000)" jdk1.8.0_40.jdk


cd /Users/myname/Desktop/XM-dev/XLIFF2Modules

codesign -s "Developer ID Application: My Name (0000000000)" XMarker.app

codesign -d --verbose=4 XMarker.app
```

[receive affirmation of correctly signed app]

```
spctl --assess --type execute XMarker.app
```

[receive no errors which = affirmation that the app will pass]

[the following I have not yet done, but expect success - if not, I will edit this part]

```
spctl --assess --type install XMarker.dmg
```

Answer (score 1):

Try going "`--deep`".

That is:

```
codesign --deep -s "Developer ID Application: My Name (0000000000)" XMarker.app
```

[Apple recommends *against* doing "`--deep`" for production releases](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG404), preferring instead to sign individual components (e.g. "jdk1.8.0_40.jdk") before embedding them into your final app.

Comment: Just want to be sure I'm reading this right. You say don't use --deep, but instead sign the jdk, and then my app, presumably in two separate command line steps? If it works I'll be overjoyed (not to mention grateful).

Comment: I'm thinking to try `-deep` to start with and if that works, then try the second approach.